# Bootstrap 4 - Column Grid Not Working Responsive

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve bootstrap 4 column. But this is not working responsive div's are overlapping each other.

How to get achieve this responsively [image: 4 column grid]

this is what I have tried but it is not working responsively

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3 height"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 height"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 height"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 height"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my css

```
.height{

height:350px;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question - what do you mean it's not responsive.  What do you mean it's overlapping?  Also TWBS4 is in alpha - everything is WIP   (Work In Progress) so the behaviour may change.  See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/xddyzfsf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">

 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
 <div class=" height">

 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class=" height">

   </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <div class=" height">

     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <div class=" height">

     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

`col-md` is for `min-width: 992px` for less than `992px` width you need to use `col-sm` class which `min-width: 768px` for less than `768px` browser width you need to use `col-xs` class. So try to use these class if you want ot make it responsive.

And CSS :
`.height{width:100%;height:350px;background: #000;}`

Comment: bootstrap 4 does not use col-xs. it's just `col-*`, e.g. `col-6`

Answer (score -2):

you can add all column divs "col-sm-6" and "col-xs-12" if you want to work full reposive.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-3 height"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 height"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 height"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 height"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this should work. i have tried on js bin

Comment: bootstrap 4 does not use col-xs. it's just `col-3`